# Load a different site in iFrame Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

I am trying to load an external page from my vue js application. The idea is to give the user experience that my application loads the other application within itself when he navigates to the page.

```
<form target ="devFrame" action="https://theothersite.jsp" ref="devform" src="#"  id="devFrame" method="post">
          <input type="hidden"  name="siteId"   :value ="siteId1"   />
          <input type="hidden" name="password"  :value ="password"  />
           
          <input type="hidden" name="loginId"  :value ="loginId1"  />
           
 

          <button  ref="submit" style="display:none " id="submitForm" type="submit"  >Submit</button>

        </form>
        <iframe  name="devFrame" id = "devFrame"  frameborder="0" width="1200" height="600" scrolling="no"  ></iframe>
```

......

```
mounted (){

  if(document.getElementById('devFrame')){
    document.getElementById('submitForm').click();
  }

}
```

When submitting the form, the hidden fields are sent to the target and the home page is rendered . However, I could not load the home page of the other site in the iframe .   I tried to open in a new window, by specifying `target="_blank"` in the  submit button and it works. But I want to load the other page within the iframe. This is all in Vue JS

Edit:

trying to connect to a third party website and display the contents in iframe. This URL in iframe does client side rendering which is not a desired option. We made few rule changes in the Nginx instance and were able to do the client side rendering, but the requirement is server side render.

Came across ssr by vue js. Have anyone tried and see it working?is that the only way or servlets JSP can help?

Comment: Why are you not just using `<iframe src="https://theothersite.jsp"/>`?

Comment: I got to load the page after login , so I submit the credentials as a hidden form..

Comment: @DanielBeck You threw some light `src="https://theothersite.jsp?&loginId=value"` and it took to the destination.. However, this wouldn't load on chrome, only on Edge

Comment: Many websites use framebreakers or other tools to prevent being framed by third parties; if what you're attempting works in a new window but not in an iframe, I would strongly expect that is because the site is deliberately preventing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are there any means other than iframe to load an external URL within my app? Tried <meta> that didnt help .

Comment: The iframe opens on Edge, not on chrome, that might be a browser restriction.